# What is the point of having tags in chat when they only show up once you are in the room?

Tags: discussion, tags, chat

[image]

In [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/), the tags which semi-depict what is on topic show up in the top right beneath the title. While this is useful when actually in the chat, I am not sure it is really worthwhile. It would probably be more useful if displayed in the tiles for joining chat which is where most new users decide which room their quandary will be most topical with.

[image]

Once a new user enters chat they have essentially decided what they are going to say, and often being unaccustomed to chat they immediately paste their prepared statement regardless of looking at the room rules or the relevant tags. Luckily, the room title usually gives away what is on topic as most rooms are organized by programming language, and basically if a topic raised revolves around that technology it is usually well received (excluding users who exhibit poor behavior, which generally has little to do with the topic and more to do with that particular user).

What I am getting at is, do the tags in chat serve any purpose? I feel like the only people aware of them are the users who are already fully aware of the room's nuances, and that new users will just ask or assume regardless of the tags being present. Further, chat real estate is pricey, and if the tags were removed, perhaps there would be more room for something else in that area.

tldr;

Are the tags in chat functional?

Comment: You can actually see them without joining a room by clicking the "info" button in the bottom-center when looking at [the chatroom list](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/). Though, I still see your point. They would probably be better served to take the place of the users because I'm not sure what good that does either

Comment: @codeMagic - Good point about info, I forgot about that piece of information. I am not sure many people click through to there at all though :) I like the idea of replacing the user tiles with the tags.

Comment: heh, that's the first time I clicked on it from there instead of actually in the room :P

Answer (score 2):

The filter on the room list works on tags as well as names.  So if the room is currently named "Reptiles" but tagged "python", it will still show up when filtering on "python".

This might be of some limited use for searching "move to chat" comment thread rooms, as the question tags are copied to the room when the thread is moved.

For example, filtering on ["[ruby]"](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/?tab=all&sort=active&filter=%5Bruby%5D) returns the Ruby room and a bunch of other discussions tagged "ruby".

Comment: It still doesn't make much sense to use screen real estate displaying them to the people already in the room. This doesn't really address the OP.

Comment: @ChrisBaker I'm not an SO dev, and I'm not psychic, so I can't comment on why they decided to put the tags where they did.  But I think this pretty clearly explains how the tags can be used in chat.

Comment: The question is "What is the point of having tags in chat" or "Are the tags functional", the answer is "you can filter on them".

Comment: You make a good point about the necessity of them here with the move to chat feature. I personally did not know you could use `[c#]` for example and get a result there. In fact, it isn't documented. I would highly doubt that more than a handful of people actually search by tag in that search bar (although I have no statistics to back this claim up).

Comment: @TravisJ yeah, I discovered it by accident.  Also, you don't need the brackets, it seems to filter on them without.

Comment: @davidism - If you try to search for just c# you get all sorts of results, basically everything that contains the letter c. I believe you do need the brackets in order for the search to properly function. It does work with the brackets though. There were a surprising amount of "private" conversations in the results which was an interesting side affect.